# Query WooCommerce orders where meta data does not exist

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, query, meta-query

I'm trying to fetch all my WooCommerce orders where some additional metadata is equal to not empty.

```
$orders = wc_get_orders( array(
    'orderby'   => 'date',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'var_rate',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        )
    )
));
```

So if the `var_rate` is empty or doesn't exist then do not return that record. At the moment all orders are returned using those arguments.

Example of empty record -

```
object(WC_Meta_Data)#2344 (2) {
  ["current_data":protected]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(6471)
    ["key"]=>
    string(15) "var_rate"
    ["value"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["data":protected]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(6471)
    ["key"]=>
    string(15) "var_rate"
    ["value"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is querying all orders which do not have the metadata `var_rate`. So if that returns all orders, then are you sure there are actually orders having that metadata? Are you sure the name is `var_rate`? And to include only orders where that metadata is not empty, you should use `'compare' => '!='` and optionally add `'value' => ''` to the array.

Comment: @SallyCJ thank you for you're response checking my data an empty value is `NULL`. I tried as you suggested and included the following `'value' => NULL` but I still get both orders. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `meta_query` argument *(that you can use in a [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query))* is not enabled by default when using a [`WC_Order_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query) through [`wc_get_orders()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_orders.html) WooCommerce function.

But for you can use the undocumented [Custom Field Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) *(just like in a `WP_Query`)*:

- `meta_key`
- `meta_value`
- `meta_value_num`
- `meta_compare`

So in your case you can use the following instead:

```
$orders = wc_get_orders( array(
    'limit'        => -1, // Query all orders
    'orderby'      => 'date',
    'order'        => 'DESC',
    'meta_key'     => 'var_rate', // The postmeta key field
    'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', // The comparison argument
));
```

This time it works nicely (Tested on WooCommerce 3.5.8 and 3.6.2).

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, WooCommerce is ignoring the `meta_query` parameter, so that's why you're getting all orders.

You can use this code to make the `meta_query` parameter works with WooCommerce (orders) queries:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_wp_query_args', function( $wp_query_args, $query_vars ){
    if ( isset( $query_vars['meta_query'] ) ) {
        $meta_query = isset( $wp_query_args['meta_query'] ) ? $wp_query_args['meta_query'] : [];
        $wp_query_args['meta_query'] = array_merge( $meta_query, $query_vars['meta_query'] );
    }
    return $wp_query_args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

But as I've pointed in my comment, to query for all orders where the `var_rate` metadata is *not* empty, set the `compare` to `!=`:

```php
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'var_rate',
        'compare' => '!=',
        'value'   => '',
    ),
),
```

And in your case where you are querying with a *single* meta query, you could simply use the `meta_key` parameter along with `meta_compare` and `meta_value`, without having to use the `meta_query` parameter:

```php
'meta_key'     => 'var_rate',
'meta_compare' => '!=',
'meta_value'   => '',
```

That way, you don't have to use the code above which "enables" the `meta_query` parameter.

### UPDATE

*I think I wasn't really paying attention to the question's title.. and I thought I should add these:*

In the question's title, you got "*where meta data does **not exist***", and for that, the `'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'` or `'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'` is what you would need.

But in the question's body, you said "*where some additional metadata is equal to **not empty***" and also "*if the `var_rate` is empty or doesn't exist then **do not return that record***", and for that, the `'compare' => '!='` or `'meta_compare' => '!='` is what you would need.

Because when the `compare` or `meta_compare` is set to `!=`, and the `value` or `meta_value` is set to `''` (the default value, if not explicitly specified), then it means, "find records where the meta exists in the database and the value is not empty (not `''` or not `NULL`)".

I hope that helps. :)